# Request for php foreach stdclass example

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

Someone please can explain me how i can get the values from entry_list in a foreach loop in php?

Following is the return data structure. Please help.

```
      stdClass Object
(
[result_count] => 1
[total_count] => 1
[next_offset] => 1
[entry_list] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 6adfd27d-0a48-48c9-97b2-5639c6d9e697
                [module_name] => Leads
                [name_value_list] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [assigned_user_name] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => assigned_user_name
                                [value] => Administrator
                            )

                        [modified_by_name] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => modified_by_name
                                [value] => Administrator
                            )

                        [created_by_name] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => created_by_name
                                [value] => Administrator
                            )

                        [id] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => id
                                [value] => 6adfd27d-0a48-48c9-97b2-5639c6d9e697
                            )
```

Comment: The key's value inside the foreach should be the one you look for

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @SulthanAllaudeen,

so if i get you correct i should do

    foreach($list as $list_items)
    {
    foreach($list_items->name_value_list as $values )
    { 
    } 
    
    }

Comment: You're welcome.. You tried by key as value to get the output ?

Comment: so if i get you correct i should do

    foreach($list as $list_items)
    {
    foreach($list_items->name_value_list as $values )
    { 
    } 
    
    }

Comment: You shall try and say ;)

Comment: `foreach($obj->entry_list as $entry)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
foreach($arr->entry_list as $row) {

     foreach($row->name_value_list as $key => $val){

          echo $key;// will echo assigned_user_name
          echo $val->name; // assigned_user_name
          echo $val->value; // Administrator

     }

}
```

Sample values are given for first row... Similarly, all values will get printed.

Comment: Thanks for the nice example, is it maybe possible to get an example to get all the values in a table , for example the values for first_name, last_name.

Comment: when i throw your code in a table it outputs something like this

http://postimg.org/image/gxn5z1dov/8d9a50fa/

Comment: you have to check for the key, if it last_name, then only echo there.

Comment: I'm sorry , you lost me there, how to check for the key if it contains last_name etc?

Comment: if($key == "last_name"){
    echo $val->value;
}